# PWA(Progressive Web App) - Launch PWA from Windows UWP application

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, progressive-web-apps, xamarin.uwp

I am working on a POC where I need to launch a PWA from Windows application instead of opening the url in the browser.

What I tried:-

1. Created a PWA and installed it on Windows.
2. Created a UWP application with Xamarin.Forms.
3. Called URL from my UWP application using `Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://localhost:8887"));`

It is opening a browser instead of my PWA.
Below is the manifest.json PWA:-

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "short_name": "Test",
  "icons": [{
    "src": "images/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    }, {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    }, {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    }, {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }, {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-256x256.png",
      "sizes": "256x256",
      "type": "image/png"
    }],
  "start_url": "/index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#3E4EB8",
  "theme_color": "#2F3BA2"
}
```

Can someone please guide me for achieving this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps/windows-features#set-up-and-run-your-universal-windows-app) to wrap your PWA as UWP app. Then, you could declare a protocol in the Package.appxmanifest file like the following:

[image]

After that, you could install it on windows and launch the url `myapp:///` from your another UWP app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Xavier. I tried the solution that you suggested. I installed my PWA as UWP and added the Protocol as you suggested. When I click on the button to open the uri windows gives me a popup saying "You'll need a new app to open this myapp". I am calling the url as Device.OpenUri(new Uri("myapp:///"));

Comment: @bakriOnFire You need to add the protocol in the Package.appxmanifest file at first, and then, you install it.

Comment: I have added the protocol in Package.appxmanifest. Building and running the application will install it in my windows machine right? Or do I need to do it in an another way?

Comment: @bakriOnFire You need to make a service like this: https://mindofai.github.io/Launching-Apps-thru-URI-with-Xamarin.Forms/

Comment: It worked for me Xavier. I had to uninstall the app and the deploy it again with the protocol(silly mistake). It worked with Device.OpenUri itself. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I have an another requirement here. Is there a possibility to call a specific page instead of the main page(landing) in the PWA app from my UWP?

Comment: @bakriOnFire You might need to [Handle URI activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation).

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I see that we can get OnActivated callback in App.xaml.cs class, but mine is a Hosted Web App. How do i get a call back of the Protocol in a hosted web application?

Comment: @bakriOnFire You need to listen for the app's activated event like this `Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("activated", function (activatedEventArgs) {// Check activatedEventArgs.kind and respond as needed
});` See [Find Windows Runtime (WinRT) APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps/windows-features#find-windows-runtime-winrt-apis) for more details.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Tried the solution that you gave but the "activated" event is never getting called. Do I need to add any extra library to get access to WinRT APIs from PWA?

Comment: `In order to call any WinRT APIs from our PWA, we'll first need to establish the requisite permissions (or, Application Content URI Rules) in your Windows app package manifest (.appxmanifest) file.` Have you checked it?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Thank you so much for the help. It was a silly mistake. I was executing the addEventListener after the page load. It is working fine now.